# How to get a table to continue onto the next page

Tags: tables, formatting, landscape

I have the following latex code which gives me a table in landscape mode, and also changes the page number from the side to the bottom:

```latex
\begin{landscape}
    
    
    \def\fillandplacepagenumber{%
        \par\pagestyle{empty}%
        \vbox to 0pt{\vss}\vfill
        \vbox to 0pt{\baselineskip0pt
            \hbox to\linewidth{\hss}%
            \baselineskip\footskip
            \hbox to\linewidth{%
                \hfil\thepage\hfil}\vss}}



\begin{table}[]\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        \hline
        Monitoring           & Thickness & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Channel Dimensions \\ (W\texttimes{} L) \textmu m\end{tabular} & Fabrication Technique & Array size   & Transconductance  & Reference  \\ \hline
        
        Heart ECG recordings & 2.6 \textmu m   & 10\texttimes{}10      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off\\ {} \end{tabular} & 4 \texttimes{}4  & 1 mS      & \textbf{x} \\
        
        
        ECoG                 & $\sim$ 1.3 \textmu m & 1600\texttimes{}8   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Photolithography \\ lift-off \\ RIE \\ {} \end{tabular}     & 4\texttimes{}4 & 139 mS & x  \\
        
                                                                  
                                                                  
        EEG rat signals      & 3 \textmu m & 70\texttimes{}20  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off\\ {} \end{tabular}  & 3\texttimes{}5  & 1.1 mS & x   \\
        
        
        
        ECG    & $\sim$ 4 \textmu m &    8\texttimes{}2   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off\\ {} \end{tabular} & 5\texttimes{}5 & 0.26 mS & x  \\
        
        
        
        EEG action potential &  $\sim$ 1 \textmu m  &  20\texttimes{}25  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off\\ {}\end{tabular}  & 4\texttimes{}4   & 2 mS     &  x \\
    
        ECoG  & $\sim$ 4 \textmu m & 15\texttimes{}6  &  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off\\ {}\end{tabular}  &  N/A   &    &            \\
    

        
        EMG &  2 \textmu m  &  5\texttimes{} 2 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off\\ {}\end{tabular}    &  5\texttimes{}5    &   1.6 mS   &      x     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\fillandplacepagenumber

\end{landscape}
```

However, when the table becomes too large for one page it then does not continue onto the next page and rotates another 90 degrees. Does anyone know how to continue the table onto the next page while keeping it in landscape orientation?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! IN case of multi page long table, you should use some of long table which should not be inserted in `table` float!

Comment: Could you explain how I should do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap text around a landscape table over multiple pages? \sidewaystable or \landscape + \longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-landscape-table-over-multiple-pages-sidewaystable-or) or [Can not split the table into two pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679096/can-not-split-the-table-into-two-pages)

Answer (score 2):

An simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}%[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{lllllll}
    \toprule
Monitoring  & Thickness             & \makecell[c]{Channel\\ Dimensions\\
                                                  (W\texttimes{} L) \textmu m}
            & Fabrication Technique & Array size
            & Transconductance      & Reference     \\
    \midrule
Heart ECG recordings
            & 2.6 \textmu m         & 10\texttimes{}10
            & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
                                    & 4 \texttimes{}4
            & 1 mS                  & \textbf{x}    \\
    \addlinespace
ECoG        & $\sim$ 1.3 \textmu m  & 1600\texttimes{}8
            & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
                                    & 4\texttimes{}4
            & 139 mS                & x  \\
    \addlinespace
EEG rat signals
            & 3 \textmu m           & 70\texttimes{}20
            & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
                                    & 3\texttimes{}5
            & 1.1 mS                & x   \\
    \addlinespace
ECG         & $\sim$ 4 \textmu m    &  8\texttimes{}2
            & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
                                    & 5\texttimes{}5
            & 0.26 mS               & x  \\
    \addlinespace
EEG action potential
            &  $\sim$ 1 \textmu m  &  20\texttimes{}25
            & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
                                    & 4\texttimes{}4
            & 2 mS                  &  x \\
    \addlinespace
ECoG       & $\sim$ 4 \textmu m    & 15\texttimes{}6
            & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
                                    &  N/A
            &                       &   \\
    \addlinespace
EMG         &  2 \textmu m          &  5\texttimes{} 2
            & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
                                    &  5\texttimes{}5
            &   1.6 mS              & x \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

- A more sophisticated solution using `tabularray` package and its libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx`. Both libraries load packages of the same name.
- In both suggestion I left out code for page layout (since this is not table writing problem, I stick with MWE (Minimal working Example) what your code example is not); desired page layout should be part of your real document
- Your table now can fit in the portrait page, and also consider:

  - `booktabs` rules for table horizontal lines
  - `siunitx` packages for writing units and quantities
  - units are written only in column headers:
  - in case, that table is longer than one page, to table will be automatically added table foot note "continued on next page" and to caption "(continued)"
- you may liked this solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{table-align-text-before=false,
         explicit-sign={\sim}
         }

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {caption text},
  label = {tab:long}
                    ]{colspec = {X[l]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format={$\sim$}1.1}] 
                                 Q[c, mode=math] 
                                 X[1.2, l] 
                                 X[0.6,c, mode=math] 
                                 X[0.8, si={table-format=3.2}] l},
                      row{1}   = {guard, mode=text, c, b}
                      }
    \toprule
Monitoring  & {Thickness\\ (\unit{\micro\meter})}
                                        & {Channel\\ Dimensions\\ (W$\times$L) \unit{\micro\meter}}
            & {Fabrication\\ Technique} & Array size
            & Transcon\-duc\-tance (\unit{\milli\siemens})        
                                        & Reference     \\
    \midrule
Heart ECG recordings
            &  2.6    & 10\times 10
            & {Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off}
                                        & 4 \times 4
            &  1    & x \\
ECoG        &  \sim 1.3   & 1600\times 8
            & {Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off}
                                        & 4\times 4
            &   139 & x  \\
EEG rat signals
            &  3      & 70\times 20
            & {Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off}
                                        & 3\times 5
            &  1.1  & x   \\
ECG         &  \sim 4     &  8\times 2
            & {Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off}
                                        & 5\times 5
            &  0.26  & x  \\
EEG action potential
            &  \sim 1     &  20\times 25
            & {Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off}
                                        & 4\times 4
            &  2      &  x \\
ECoG        &  \sim 4     & 15\times 6
            & {Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off}
                                        &  N/A
            &                           &   \\
EMG         &   2   &  5\times  2
            & {Photolithography \\ RIE \\ lift-off}
                                        &  5\times 5
            &  1.6  & x \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Just a slight issue that the page number is on the left-hand side, now. But good progress!

Comment: @kieranm, I focus on table only, I didn't bother with your page design. This I left to you (that you will add dropped code line from your example). BTW, this is not only progres, this is valid answer/ solution on your quesry.