# How can I fit my longtable within the page limit

Tags: longtable, width, page

I have the following table code:

```
\begin{longtable}{lllllll} 
    
    \toprule
    Monitoring  & Thickness             & \makecell[c]{Channel\\ Dimensions\\
        (W\texttimes{} L) \textmu m}
    & Fabrication Technique & Array size
    & Transconductance      & Reference     \\
    \midrule
    
    
    Heart ECG recordings
    & 2.6 \textmu m         & 10\texttimes{}10
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 4 \texttimes{}4
    & 1 mS                  & \textbf{x}    \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    ECoG        & $\sim$ 1.3 \textmu m  & 1600\texttimes{}8
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 4\texttimes{}4
    & 139 mS                & x  \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    EEG rat signals
    & 3 \textmu m           & 70\texttimes{}20
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 3\texttimes{}5
    & 1.1 mS                & x   \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    ECG         & $\sim$ 4 \textmu m    &  8\texttimes{}2
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 5\texttimes{}5
    & 0.26 mS               & x  \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    EEG action potential
    &  $\sim$ 1 \textmu m  &  20\texttimes{}25
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 4\texttimes{}4
    & 2 mS                  &  x \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    ECoG       & $\sim$ 4 \textmu m    & 15\texttimes{}6
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    &  N/A  &     0.9 mS        &  x   \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    EMG         &  2 \textmu m          &  5\texttimes{} 2
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    &  5\texttimes{}5
    &   1.6 mS              & x \\
    
        Heart ECG recordings
    & 2.6 \textmu m         & 10\texttimes{}10
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 4 \texttimes{}4
    & 1 mS                  & \textbf{x}    \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    ECoG        & $\sim$ 1.3 \textmu m  & 1600\texttimes{}8
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 4\texttimes{}4
    & 139 mS                & x  \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    EEG rat signals
    & 3 \textmu m           & 70\texttimes{}20
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 3\texttimes{}5
    & 1.1 mS                & x   \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    ECG         & $\sim$ 4 \textmu m    &  8\texttimes{}2
    & \makecell[l]{Photolithography \\ RIE\\ lift-off}
    & 5\texttimes{}5
    & 0.26 mS               & x  \\
    \addlinespace
    
    
    
    \bottomrule
    
    
    \caption{OECTs for biophysical signal sensing}
    \label{Table: OECT biophysical sensing}
\end{longtable}%
```

However, it does not stay within the page width.
Could someone help me with this.

Comment: You already have been asked for a minimal working example for almost the same code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683890). Without such a minimal working example, we even don't know the size of your pages (or the text area). So how could we tell you, what to change to make it fit into the page width?

Comment: You use my code from my answer, it will be nice to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer), isn't it? Also see addendum to my answer. It solve here reported problem too. BTW, please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which we can test as it is. Now we haven't any information about your document page layout. whivh has strong influence on posible table layout

Comment: Please tell us why you're employing a `longtable` environment.

Comment: @Mico, see OP previous question and my answer on it. It is not clear at all what (s)he is after.

Comment: Hey, I understand you're experts at this, but have a little appreciation for people who aren't as into this as you. I'm not really sure what I'm doing with this program as I'm new with it - try to be a little more understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a good reason for employing a `longtable` environment. I'd use a `tabularx` environment (with a target width of `\textwidth`) embedded inside a `table` environment. I'd also allow automatic line breaking in 5 of the 7 columns in order to make the table fit inside the width of the text block. I'd further place repeated elements, such as the units of measurement in columns 2 and 6, in the headers, mainly to help declutter the table's appearance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for '\unit' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\hyphenation{trans-con-duct-ance photo-lith-og-raphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}  % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L CCCcCc @{}}    
\toprule

    Monitoring 
    & Thickness (\unit{\micro\meter})
    & Channel Dim.\ (W\texttimes L) \unit{\micro\meter}
    & Fabrication Technique 
    & Array size
    & Transconductance (mS)
    & Ref. \\

\midrule 
    
    Heart ECG recordings
    & 2.6 
    & $10\times10$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $4\times4$
    & 1 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace    
    
    ECoG        
    & ${\approx}1.3$ 
    & $1600\times8$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $4\times4$
    & 139 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
      
    EEG rat signals
    & 3 
    & $70\times20$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $3\times5$
    & 1.1 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
       
    ECG 
    & ${\approx}4$
    & $8\times2$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $5\times5$
    & 0.26 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
       
    EEG action potential
    & ${\approx}1$ 
    & $20\times25$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $4\times4$
    & 2 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
      
    ECoG 
    & ${\approx}4$ 
    & $15\times6$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & N/A 
    & 0.9 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
    
    EMG 
    & 2 
    & $5\times2$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $5\times5$
    & 1.6 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
    
    Heart ECG recordings
    & 2.6 
    & $10\times10$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off 
    & $4\times4$
    & 1 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
    
    ECoG 
    & ${\approx}1.3$ 
    & $1600\times8$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $4\times4$ 
    & 139 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
    
    EEG rat signals
    & 3 
    & $70\times20$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $3\times5$ 
    & 1.1 
    & x \\
    \addlinespace
       
    ECG 
    & ${\approx}4$ 
    & $8\times2$
    & Photolithography RIE lift-off
    & $5\times5$
    & 0.26 
    & x \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{OECTs for biophysical signal sensing}
\label{Table:OECTBiophysicalSensing}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, my only problem is that if I continue adding rows to the table it will continue off the bottom of the page, do you know how I can get it to go to the next page?

Comment: @kieranm - I suggest you look into using an [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) environment, which combines the capabilities of the `longtable` and `xtabular` environments.

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Comment: @kieranm - Just noticed a mistake in my earlier comment: I meant to write `tabularx`, not `xtabular`.